# What public testnets (test networks) and faucets exist?

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development, testnets, testing, faucets

What public test-networks exist and what are their conditions?

1. What are the connection data?
2. How often (if so) are they reset?
3. Does a public faucet exist for this test network?
4. Does a block explorer exist for this test network?
5. How frequent/ reliable are new blocks mined?
6. Any thing else user should know about this test network?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/how-to-get-ether-on-public-testnet/21307#21307

Answer (score 27):

| Chain | Chain ID | Layer | Faucets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ethereum*: Goerli [Explorer](https://goerli.etherscan.io/) | 5 | L1 | https://goerlifaucet.com (account required) https://faucet.quicknode.com/ethereum/goerli |
| Ethereum*: Sepolia [Explorer](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/) | 11155111 | L1 | https://sepoliafaucet.com (account required) https://faucet-sepolia.rockx.com https://fauceth.komputing.org https://faucet.quicknode.com/ethereum/sepolia |
| BNB Smart Chain: TestNet [Explorer](https://testnet.bscscan.com/) | 97 | L1 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/binance-smart-chain/bnb-testnet |
| Avalanche: Fuji [Explorer](https://testnet.avascan.info/) | 43113 | L1 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/avalanche/fuji |
| Solana: DevNet Explorer [1](https://solana.fm/?cluster=devnet-solana) [2](https://solscan.io/?cluster=devnet) [3](https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=devnet) | n/a** | L1 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/solana/devnet |
| Solana: TestNet Explorer [1](https://solana.fm/?cluster=testnet-solana) [2](https://solscan.io/?cluster=testnet) [3](https://explorer.solana.com/?cluster=testnet) | n/a** | L1 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/solana/testnet |
| Polygon PoS: Mumbai [Explorer](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/) | 80001 | L2 | https://mumbaifaucet.com https://faucet.polygon.technology/ https://faucet.quicknode.com/polygon/mumbai |
| Polygon zkEVM: Goerli [Explorer](https://testnet-zkevm.polygonscan.com/) | 1442 | L2 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/polygon/zkevm-goerli |
| Optimism: Goerli [Explorer](https://goerli-optimism.etherscan.io/) | 420 | L2 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/optimism/goerli |
| Arbitrum: Goerli [Explorer](https://goerli.arbiscan.io/) | 421613 | L2 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/arbitrum/goerli |
| Base: Goerli [Explorer](https://goerli.basescan.org/) | 84531 | L2 | https://faucet.quicknode.com/base/goerli |

*All other Ethereum Layer 1 TestNets are deprecated, like Rinkeby and Ropsten.

**Solana does not have the concept of Chain IDs. Their most closely related concept would be a [cluster](https://docs.solana.com/clusters).

Answer (score 13):

#### B9lab's IPFS faucet with command line access

B9lab have [one deployed via IPFS](https://blog.b9lab.com/when-we-first-built-our-faucet-we-deployed-it-on-the-morden-testnet-70bfbf4e317e#.2apa6lg4p). this is pretty neat. long description below, here is the one-liner for rushed users:

```
curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"toWhom":"0xdcf407eae88d480e280db2d0deaa3a11c82eaa9b"}' https://ropsten.faucet.b9lab.com/tap
```

Replace 0xdcf407... with your testnet account. It will send 1 ETH by default. If you need more, you need to go to the IPFS interface:

```
$ geth --testnet --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3"

# in another terminal
$ ipfs daemon
```

And [visit localhost][2]. There is also an [IPFS gateway available][3] for the lazy.

#### Ether camp ropsten faucet

Navigating to [ropsten.ether.camp](https://ropsten.ether.camp/) shows a huge button `GET FREE ETHER` at the top of the explorer. Click it, enter your address and recieve 5 test ETH.

[2]: http://localhost:8080/ipfs/QmVAwVKys271P5EQyEfVSxm7BJDKWt42A2gHvNmxLjZMps  [3]: http://ipfs.b9lab.com:8080/ipfs/QmVAwVKys271P5EQyEfVSxm7BJDKWt42A2gHvNmxLjZMps

Comment: As of May 13th neither of these work any more.

Comment: Yeah, ropsten is a moving target, hard to keep track of the changes.

Comment: The B9lab faucet does work. You are in competition with other people because it yields 1 Ether per minute. Not 1 Ether per minute per person. It also has some simple measures against abuse.

Comment: BTW, if someone has a lot of Ropsten Ethers lying around, feel free to send some to this faucet as it is getting harder to mine them.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab sent 10k, please ping me on Gitter if you need more.

Comment: That was you then :+1:

Comment: @ThomasClowes the `curl` script just worked for me...

Answer (score 4):

(Adding another answer rather than updating the community wiki answer, as it would involve changing most of what's there, and it may well be historically useful.)

> What public test-networks exist and what are their conditions?

1. ROPSTEN (Revived, following [spam attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12477/ropsten-testnet-is-under-kind-of-attack-what-can-we-do)) - Proof Of Work
2. KOVAN - Proof Of Authority (Parity only)
3. RINKEBY - Clique Consensus (Geth only)

---

> What are the connection data?

**Geth:** (Ropsten/Rinkeby)

Either specify the network using the ID (`3` = Ropsten, `4` = Rinkeby) or using the `--testnet` or `--rinkeby` flags.

```
 --networkid value                    Network identifier (integer, 1=Frontier, 2=Morden (disused), 3=Ropsten, 4=Rinkeby) (default: 1)
  --testnet                            Ropsten network: pre-configured proof-of-work test network
  --rinkeby
```

**Parity:** (Ropsten/Kovan)

Use the `--chain` flag.

```
 --chain CHAIN                  Specify the blockchain type. CHAIN may be either a
                                 JSON chain specification file or olympic, frontier,
                                 homestead, mainnet, morden, ropsten, classic, expanse,
                                 testnet, kovan or dev (default: homestead).
```

---

> How often (if so) are they reset?

- Ropsten has been live for 241 days (as of 19 Jul 2017).
- Kovan has been live for 139 days.
- Rinkeby has been live for 98 days.

---

> Does a public faucet exist for this test network?

- ropsten: http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/ (has been known to have problems)
- ropsten: https://blog.b9lab.com/when-we-first-built-our-faucet-we-deployed-it-on-the-morden-testnet-70bfbf4e317e - *the "script ninja" part worked for user atomh33ls (16-08-2017)*
- kovan: https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet (i.e. Gitter service)
- rinkeby: https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

---

> Does a block explorer exist for this test network?

- https://ropsten.etherscan.io/
- https://kovan.etherscan.io/
- https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/

---

> How frequent/ reliable are new blocks mined?

- Ropsten block time = usually sub-30 seconds
- Kovan block time = seems to be sub-10 seconds
- Rinkeby block time = 15 seconds (by definition?)

---

> Any thing else user should know about this test network?

Don't assign value to test ether.

Answer (score 3):

Just a heads up, we have created a universal Faucet [here](https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow)

The idea is to put as many networks together (and tokens) to make the experience smoother for developers.

Comment: Just a heads up, your website is down.

Answer (score 3):

**UDPATED OCT 2022** - Goerli is now the *only* Ethereum testnet! Rinkeby, Ropsten, and Kovan are all deprecated because of the recent Ethereum merge.

If you need a reliable faucet, Alchemy has a good one - **[goerlifaucet.com](https://goerlifaucet.com)**. You just sign up for a free account, and you can get more free Goerli testETH every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

**March 2023 Update**

GOERLI - There's a shortage in Goerli. If you need Goerli, you can use Alchemy's faucet: https://goerlifaucet.com.

SEPOLIA - Alchemy has launched support for Sepolia testnet and a free Sepolia faucet: https://sepoliafaucet.com.

From these faucet, you can get more testETH every day. Please only take what you need so there's enough for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

A good list of public faucets can be found on https://faucetlink.to/

If you want to run a validator on Prater or Ropsten, you can join [the EthStaker Discord server](https://discord.io/ethstaker) and access the #request-goerli-eth or the #request-ropsten-eth channel with a BrightID verified account to get enough testnet ETH to do your deposit.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Aug 2022:

- https://rinkebyfaucet.com
  0.5 eth (need sign with Alchemy, which is free)
- https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby
  0.1 eth

Comment: Rinkeby (Ropsten and Kovan) are now all deprecated (AKA not working) bc of the Ethereum merge. Goerli is now the only Ethereum testnet. Alchemy also has a free Goerli faucet where you can get more testETH every 24 hours - goerlifaucet.com.

Answer (score 0):

As for **May 2023** there are 2 public test-networks: **Goerli** (Chain ID: 5) and **Sepolia** (Chain ID: 11155111).

They both have testnet explorers:

Goerli: https://goerli.etherscan.io/

Sepolia: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/

To get free tokens you can use Alchemy's faucets: https://goerlifaucet.com and https://sepoliafaucet.com.

If you need more test tokens than these faucets provide you can buy some, as an altcoin [GETH](https://etherscan.io/token/0xdd69db25f6d620a7bad3023c5d32761d353d3de9?a=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) (Goerli ETH on mainnet) is available to buy on Uniswap and LayerZero made a bridge between mainnet and Goerli testnet. The site is https://testnetbridge.com. Swap and Bridge has a gas limit of 370,000 and depending on gas price the cost of transaction can be from few to even tens of dollars. To skip that high fee you can use a service from https://www.goerlieth.com/, where you can buy Goerli ETH starting from $1. They accept transfers on many networks, including Polygon that has really cheap fees.

Good luck with your projects!

Answer (score 0):

Free Sepolia Testnet Faucet that lets you claim 0.5 Sepolia ETH per day.

https://www.infura.io/faucet/sepolia

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.buildbear.io/ and create your own Testnet that comes with a built-in faucet.