# find out network using contract address

Tags: contract-deployment, addresses

I know that in Ethereum, same addresses works across the network(mainnet and all testnets).

But I am looking to know if there are any chances to find out the network on which a contract is deployed by using its contract address because only relevant network will be having the data of contract stored.

Also how much reliable this approach can be?

Comment: This is also related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18314/is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-between-an-account-on-the-main-net-and-the-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this is not the best solution but can be helpful for now:

set web3 provider for every testnet one by one and then try to get the size of the contract using following web3 call.

`web3.eth.getCode(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])`

this returns the data if the address is a contract.

> you may get the data from multiple chains.
>   In this case you'll end up with multiple networks having code for same address.

Comment: seems reasonable

Answer (score 1):

You may try to find this address in https://etherscan.io/ on different networks and see where it has some code or non-zero ether balance:

- https://etherscan.io/
- https://ropsten.etherscan.io/
- https://kovan.etherscan.io/
- https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/
- https://goerli.etherscan.io/
- https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/

Etherscan also has an [API](https://etherscan.io/apis) for this that you can use to automate such lookups.

Comment: makes sense....