# What is my Testnet ether worth?

Tags: mining, ether, testnets

I started mining on the testnet and my main account (Etherbase) is getting ether quickly. It started 20 min ago and already have almost 300 ether and counting, which I think is a lot of money.

Is it just fake because I am on testnet? Is it not really ether, but something which is not worth that much?

Comment: Related (answer to the above question is implicit in this one): [What prevents the market from assigning value to testnet ETH?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/what-prevents-the-market-from-assigning-value-to-testnet-eth)

Answer (score 3):

The testnet cryptocurrency has no value and is restarted regularly. The only point mining on testnet is graciously helping to maintain the testnet blockchain. And actually I am not sure it helps much.