# How to get ether on public testnet?

Tags: mining, ether, testnets, faucets

I am a newbee to Ethereum and doing some research. I have installed the Ethereum Wallet app and synchronized the testnet.

However, to deploy my first contract in testnet, it requires some Ether, so can someone guide how to get that? I have tried to mine in testnet but unable to earn anything yet. So, are there any other ways?

Comment: Could you provide more details about the outputs you got when you started mining? I guess the accounts in test-net are pre-allocated with 10 ether each. Check [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Morden#getting-ether) for getting more ether.

Comment: Related, because testnets change: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist

Answer (score 18):

The 2 best ways I found were:

1) Instant: an ether faucet here: 
http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

2) An hour or two: Switch on Mining from the menu Develop > Start Mining (Testnet only) or Command Shift M

You'll instantly have 1 ETH for each address you send to the faucet, and 20 or 30 test ETH from mining in a few hours at least.

Comment: 1) did not work for me - no ETH in my wallet even after 10mins

Comment: Can we write some code using web3? I can't use the methods like above in my final year project!

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 16):

you can get ethers on the testnet simply by using **Metamask plugin**. here's how:

You need beforehand install metamask plugin from [here](https://metamask.io/), then follow the steps shown in the following picture :
**1-press buy button :**
[image]

**2- press the ropsten test faucet button** :
[image]
**3-** you will be redirect to https://faucet.metamask.io/ then request your free ethers.

[image]

Comment: Is it normal that it's been more than 20min and I haven't received anything yet

Comment: This method worked for me and within 2 minutes I got 3 Ethers

Answer (score 8):

Update: test networks doesn't use PoW anymore, but PoA. You have to ask money by faucet.

- Rinkeby PoA: https://faucet.rinkeby.io/
- Kovan PoA: https://faucet.metamask.io/

You could use metamask for Kovan too. Just install metamask.

Outdated: In Ethereum-Wallet, there was an option for **CPU mining** in the *Develop menu*. Use it to mine ethers (and win ethers). If you can't mine, you should have a problem (probably network). On Homestead (the production network), cpu mining is inefficient.

Otherwise, i recommend you to create your own private blockchain. You could use our script to build one in two lines: https://github.com/regispietra/CreatePrivateEthereum
With this script, you install a blockchain and can use Ethereum wallet.

Comment: Option for **CPU mining** in the Develop menu is not shown as of march 2018, they may have removed it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of 'faucets' which will send you Ether on the testnet so that you can get started. Several of these have easy web interfaces which you can simply copy-and-paste your address into- this may be easiest if you're just getting started with Wallet. I had luck sending ether to my initial account with [this faucet](http://faucet.ma.cx:3000/); once you have some intial ether you can create a wallet contract or run smart contracts.

I unsuccessfully tried using the [zerogox faucet](https://zerogox.com/ethereum/wei_faucet) to send ether to the main account created by Wallet- it appears that the zerogox faucet may only be set up to send to wallet contracts on the blockchain, not externally owned accounts. However, once I had created my first wallet contract, the zerogox faucet worked fine for filling it with wei!

Comment: The first link [http://faucet.ma.cx:3000/] is broken

Answer (score 1):

There are so called "faucets", API endpoints that send you ether on the testnet (called morden).
I created a CLI script to make this easier for you. Just pass in your testnet wallet address and et voila: ether gets sent to you.

p.s. I am in the process of creating a own faucet for this one. The public ones turn out to change in quality and availability.

[ethrain cli script](https://github.com/sebs/ethrain)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Ropsten test network, you can use a faucet.

A faucet provides you with a small amount of Ether for free.

My company built a faucet which can be found [here](https://ethtools.com/ropsten/tools/faucet/).

A video outlining its usage can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoxxZD9afpk).