# How to get testnet ether?

Tags: ether, testnets, faucets

https://youtu.be/NBwRXpCQta8

I watched this video and followed it.

But my account test ether is zero.
[image: Screenshot: Ether = 0]

I used faucet.ma.cx:3000 site too.

But test ether is zero.

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/how-to-get-ether-on-public-testnet and http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist

Comment: 0x3cf387E565cb7466d2a334A6DeD2BBe3CA0242Eb

Answer (score 7):

There are two/three ways to get ether on your own private testnet:

1. Using Faucet as you did (i would not do this that way).
2. Mining: as mining in your own testnet (probably with lower mining difficulty) is far much easier, you can get tons of ether quickly.
3. Generating a custom Genesis file for your testnet and pre-allocating some ether.

Check this: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options

And this: https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

Comment: Doesn't 3 work only on a private testnet?

Comment: I already said at the beginning of my answer: "There are two/three ways to get ether on your own private testnet:" So yes, i was answering the question about how to get ether on a testnet.

Comment: How can faucets work on a private testnet??

Comment: Depending on if the faucet may be (or not) the chance to make some modifications on faucet configuration. (To be sincere i don't know if faucets work that way or not)

Answer (score 3):

The ether faucet I used is not available anymore so I removed the link. They come and go, but try looking for "testnet ether faucet", there is often at least one that works.

It's a website than you can use periodically to send one or a few testnet ethers to an adress.

---

If you're not on the Morden (now Ropsten) testnet (I believe you're on a private blockchain), manually change the genesis file and add :

```
"alloc": {
"<0xyouraddress>": {
    "balance": "10000000000000000000"
}
}
```

Then run geth again.

Comment: The link is dead, consider removing it.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Thanks. Stuff on here get obsolete really fast, it's crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the screenshot I'd say that you are still downloading the blockchain  and your account will be updated with current ETH balance once syncing is complete.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get some Ether for the Ropsten test network, you can request some from the EthTools.com [Ropsten Faucet](https://ethtools.com/ropsten/tools/faucet/).

There is even a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoxxZD9afpk) outlining exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I mined the testnet for a couple of hours and got over 2,000 ether.

To mine:
1.  Open Ethereum wallet.
2.  Select the testnet (Develop -> Network -> testnet).
3.  Switch on mining (Develop -> Start Mining).

Remember that there are usually only one or two peers worldwide using the testnet.  The blockchain is smaller and the brute force required for the main Ethereum or the Bitcoin mining is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be to go on Gitter chat room of go-ethereum and just post your address and ask for some test ether. Someone will definitely give you some ether.

https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum

Answer (score 1):

I Personally used the 2nd option enumerated by KanekiDev.

When you start the console the first time the chain configuration is loaded from the genesis.json file, the best way is set a lot of eth in the alloc section:

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 15, 
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0
},
"difficulty": "20",
"gasLimit": "2100000",
"alloc": {
"7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": 
    { "balance": "9000000000000000" },
"ce307b175708fbebfd4b0ae8a5e877cf403e473d": 
    { "balance": "9000000000000000" }
}
}
```

Instead, if you try to add more eth to an already created testnet, you need to start mining for a couple of minutes and you will get a lot of eth.

in your Geth console just type this:

```
miner.start()
```

if you want to know how much Eth you get, just type in your console:

```
 eth.getBalance("ce307b175708fbebfd4b0ae8a5e877cf403e473d")
```

and you will see the new balance for you address.
When you want to stop mining:

```
miner.stop()
```

If you want to get Eth in rinkeby for example I used this Faucet: 
https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

I just wrotte in my facebook (you can use twitter if you want) and paste the publication link in the faucet:

> More rinkeby ether please 0x7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82

and you will get some Eth in your server

Answer (score 0):

I regularly use this faucet which works simply and reliably:

http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue even with faucets that the ethers were not able to transfer to my wallet (Ethereum Wallet 0.9.3 and Geth 1.7.2), I did this.

- Choose RopSten Test Network
- Once you choose it you will able to see the option of `Start Mining` in `Develop` menu.
- Click on start mining and you will notice that the ethers are increasing in your account.

Posting it here for newbies like me. I didn't know how to get started (have more ethers so I can deploy my own contract) but didn't find anything useful. And hence posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this, but you can do a couple things to get testnet eth:

- Mine ETH for yourself on rospsten, it's somewhat easy to do but can be time consuming and resource intensive (power and computing)
- Use a faucet like this one: https://faucet.egorfine.com
- You can also buy ropsten eth with tools like [ropsten.money](https://www.ropsten.money/l/ropsten) (full disclosure: I made ropsten.money)