# Ethereum Wallet on Testnet to mine

Tags: mining, ether, wallets

I have installed the ethereum wallet on widows. But my account ether balance is 0.00 ether.  Then I started mining from developer network(Test only). But it shows nothing, I could not get any ether mined and waited for whole day too.
  I've tried some possibilities on free mining from other faucet mining sites to claim some free there, it doesn't reflect on my account.
 Could you please help me on this to get some ether for my account?

Comment: We need more info, version of wallet and geth and if you have the sync finished or not, for example.

Comment: version 0.8.10, all the blocks are sync

Comment: Try yo use a metamask faucet for put some eths in your account. For solve the problem of mining i dont' know what is happening, check if you have all correctly installed and if the correct ports are open, but if you are sync this is not posible but check it. And the 0.8.10 is the version of the wallet, no ?

Comment: provide your address i'll send you some eth to make your tests

Comment: There are a few test networks (such as the new Ropsten, Kovan, and Rinkeby); you should specify which one you're using so as to get ether on the right network!

Comment: Here is the best way to get fake ETH on Ropsten network
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/21307/14786

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it doesn't show it's mining.

However on activating the mining, CPU and disks start going crazy, and it shows in the logs in

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\node.log

```
INFO [07-14|11:52:05] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [07-14|11:52:05] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [07-14|11:52:05] Starting mining operation 
INFO [07-14|11:52:05] Commit new mining work                   number=1296848 txs=0   uncles=0 elapsed=500.9µs
INFO [07-14|11:52:23] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=1   mgas=0.088  elapsed=5.513ms   mgasps=16.047 number=1296848 hash=cf3536…d18c42
INFO [07-14|11:52:23] Commit new mining work                   number=1296849 txs=1   uncles=0 elapsed=1.002ms
INFO [07-14|11:52:37] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=1   mgas=0.044  elapsed=7.017ms   mgasps=6.257  number=1296849 hash=d87334…51fb17
INFO [07-14|11:52:37] Commit new mining work                   number=1296850 txs=0   uncles=0 elapsed=1.503ms
...
```

You can check in your logs that indeed mining starts.

However the problem is that I can't stop the mining unless I exit the program.

Comment: This seems like an answer, followed by a comment. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can get some Ether from this faucet:
http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

Comment: That faucet is not working since some time ago.

Comment: I got Ether from it a couple days ago

Answer (score 0):

There is a bot plus a manual human backup for the Ropsten Testnet faucet at [If you need some Ropsten Testnet ethers...](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/61zdn8/if_you_need_some_ropsten_testnet_ethers/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is mining involved on the Test networks. They don't use PoW. They use [Proof of Authority](https://wiki.parity.io/Proof-of-Authority-Chains) (PoA) which means only authorized nodes can mine (process) transactions and receive the "fake" reward...

Best way to get ether to your test account is to use the faucets like https://faucet.metamask.io/

Metamask has faucets for all test networks