# Issues connecting to the Etherscan Ropsten API via web3.py

Tags: ropsten, web3.py, testrpc-to-ropsten

I am developing a simple application that transfers tokens between users. The token in an ERC20 standard token.

I am really new to the web3 and ethereum development world and I am confused by quite a few things. It would be nice I someone could show where my mistake is.

The contract for the token in deployed on the ropsten testnet and I wanted to call balanceOf() and transfer() functions. However, calling the balanceOf() function in form .call().balanceOf() gives an error:

> ```
> File "/home/blah/blah/transactions.py", line 26, in <module>
>     CONTRACT.call().balanceOf("0x70d704ab702097427Bba427492c86493e8B7597b") File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 772, in call_contract_function
>     return_data = contract.web3.eth.call(call_transaction)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3/eth.py", line 266, in call
>     formatted_transaction = formatters.input_transaction_formatter(self, transaction)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/eth_utils/string.py", line 71, in inner
>     return fn(*text_args, **text_kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/eth_utils/string.py", line 85, in inner
>     return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3/formatters.py", line 125, in input_transaction_formatter
>     'from': eth.coinbase,   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/eth_utils/string.py", line 85, in inner
>     return force_obj_to_text(fn(*args, **kwargs))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3/eth.py", line 70, in coinbase
>     return self.web3._requestManager.request_blocking("eth_coinbase", [])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3/providers/manager.py", line 30, in request_blocking
>     response = json.loads(force_text(response_raw))   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
>     return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
>     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
> ```

I am not sure if this is an error regarding HTTPProvider not connecting to the "https://ropsten.etherscan.io", or is the url that I have used to the HTTPProvider not correct for the ropsten testnet, or some other issue. I have double checked the contract address as well as the contract ABI. Or is it some problem regarding lack of gas/ether associated with account?

I tried testing another similar contract on the private testnet, and the same code was working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [This might be] an error regarding HTTPProvider not connecting to the "https://ropsten.etherscan.io"

That's correct, you cannot use the [etherscan.io API](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/apis#proxy) as a JSON-RPC server.

Instead, I'd recommend running an Ethereum node locally that is synced with Ropsten, similar to how (I presume) you ran the private testnet.

One way to do that would be:

```
parity --chain ropsten
```

You can then connect with:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
assert web3.isConnected()
```

Naturally, you'll need to create an account before the `balanceOf()` call will work. For the `transfer()` function to work, you'll also need to send the account [ropsten ether](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/how-to-get-ether-on-public-testnet).

### API Comparison

Let's look at how each API sends the latest block number.

**Etherscan**

To get the current block number with the [etherscan.io API](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/apis#proxy), you would use a GET call, specifying `eth_blockNumber` as the `action` parameter.

> **eth_blockNumber**
>   Returns the number of most recent block
>
> ```
> https://ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_blockNumber&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
> ```

like so:

```
curl "https://ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_blockNumber"
```

**Ethereum JSON-RPC server**

In contrast, [JSON-RPC specifies the API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_blocknumber) as a POST call, with `eth_blockNumber` sent as the `method` parameter, like so:

```
// Request
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}'

// Result
{
  "id":83,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": "0x4b7" // 1207
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I think this should work now.

Comment: Your did answer my original query and thank you for that. But I am facing another error when I'm trying to call contract functions. When I try using **call()** it says  "web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?" and when I try using **transact()** it says "raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}". I am working on calling ERC20 token contract functions.

Comment: Does that mean I should first fully sync with Ropsten chain? And If yes, does that mean if the contract is later deployed in the main net, I should fully sync with the main net as well?

Comment: Yes, you will need to be synced to interact with the blockchain.