# Not receiving wei from Morden faucet

Tags: transactions, synchronization, morden, faucets

I am new to Ethereum. I tried getting some wei from the faucets referenced [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist), in particular, from [zerogox](https://zerogox.com/ethereum/wei_faucet) and [morden.ether.camp](https://morden.ether.camp/account/3c5C5A4173EA6fD65acab7C0d9B4b249C438973B). It says on these websites that I have been sent wei (see e.g., screenshot below). That was more than a day ago.

However, I see no change in my balance on my Ethereum wallet (see second screenshot). My wallet tells me about 1 minutes passed since the last block (i.e., fully sync as far as I as understand).

**Have I received the wei, but cannot see it?**

**Am I seeing the correct balance, and I have not received the wei?**

**Why?**

Thank you.

[image: zerogox]

[image: my wallet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this happens because the **morden** testnet was [forked](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/) at the block 1885000 (no more exists), now the Ethereum network support the **Ropsten** testnet. so the previous faucet provider will not send you any weis (after the Nov-20-2016, 06:12:20 +UTC fork date). to get free ether i think it is easy to mine them on the new testnet using an ethereum client or use a faucet service for ropsten like http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/.

[image]

Comment: ooookk thanks. So my client (v. 0.8.7), in testnet mode, is synchronizing with Ropsten "by default"?

Comment: read the article https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/ it descrbes how to do (geth --datadir /path/to/testnet/data init genesis.json; geth --datadir /path/to/testnet/data --networkid 3 console), don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: although I read this article, I am afraid I don't really understand. If my client is synced with morden and morden is not supported by the network, why do I see new blocks every few seconds? If on the other hand, my client is synchronized with ropsten (I ld like to know indeed), thereby explaining why I see new blocks,  why do I need to enter the above commands? I am grateful for your help. But the article you provided does not give much explanation to noobs.

Comment: Ropsten is an entirely new blockchain, whith its own genesis block so if you didn't run the command with the new genesis file as mentioned in the article you are then still in the morden testnet. you could receive blocks because there is some other miners who didn't noticed that morden is no more. So update your client and join the new testnet

Comment: thk u very much. To close this top with a last question: since there are some miners left, and presumably the faucet has not moved to ropsten either (at least as per the message they display), should I expect my balance to rise some time (perhaps are they few miners and it takes longer to be written in the blockchain), or never?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand the question