# Get some eth on testnet ethereum waller

Tags: ether, testnets

Hello iam newbee in blockchain, i install ethereum wallet on my windows and create wallet in testnet network. Can i somehow get some eth for free for testing contract? I trying to mining but its not working yet.How many time i should to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i somehow get some eth for free for testing contract?

You can also use a faucet, instead of worrying about trying to mine.

See the answer to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist) previous question for details, but it basically boils down to visiting http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the block syncing to complete.

Once the syncing is complete you can start mining.

On the console you can execute "eth.syncing". When it is set to false it means syncing is done. Otherwise it will show you the difference of the block number for your syncing process to complete.

You can also check your data folder to see the increase in block syncing data whether happening or not.

**Default Testnet Data folder**

> C:\Users\(user id)\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\geth\chaindata

Block syncing does take some time.