# Problem getting any test ether from rinkeby or ropsten

Tags: ether

Could someone please send me some test ether
Mywallet address is 0xc7Cf32F77ad5CE20871Be32F1f9A9f05a980cA0f
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello, @Lubwama. Please make sure to ask appropriate questions in the future. Instead of asking people to send you test ETH in the future, you could ask them for where to find test ETH and have them post resources that other users would also benefit from. The question seems to have already been answered here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist

Comment: I tried all the available test ETH sites and they were down. I thought I could simply ask and someone would be willing to help. I didn't think I'd be riduculed for asking. Well done  Sir 

Comment: Sorry, @Lubwama. My intention was not to ridicule. We need to keep a high quality of content on the StackExchange for the benefit of the entire community. It's really important for me to discourage any posts that could add noise to the collective knowledge base. That being said, I understand that you're new here and would love to help you out any way I can.

Comment: I understand. I'll be sure to ask better questions that can contribute to the community. Iam new to crypto and am willing to accept any help thats available. A road map on how best to approach learning blockchain would be invaluable

Comment: Well, I would start by learning how Bitcoin works under the hood, and only then I would read about Ethereum and how it works. There's no better resource to learn any technology that to read the whitepaper, but I think that could be too much for someone just starting. I would suggest starting with the following videos:
https://youtu.be/Lx9zgZCMqXE
https://youtu.be/OwSl2xwl2-w