# Hi guys i hope to get some help  i am a begineer and i need some testnet ETH please some help

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, metamask, nft, ethereum-wallet-dapp

[Eth need abehri ayoub please some help](https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=pfbid077U6Z4PLQc4MfZhVakv7FDQ1SwxSApFvpX2iggKNzh2TcvEuKschdwWNGWq1TWJVl&id=100089298456836&mibextid=Nif5oz)

Comment: You can get some ether for public test networks using some of the faucet available https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84/what-public-test-networks-and-faucets-exist.